# set max number of pages to 5 using ng-simplepaginator in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am using ng-simplePagination plugin for pagination.
It is working fine, but it is showing all the page numbers in the view.

How do i restrict the page size to 5.

https://github.com/svileng/ng-simplePagination

I added `limitTo : pagination.maxPages`, but not working.

```
<li ng-repeat="n in [] | range: pagination.numPages | limitTo : pagination.maxPages" ng-class="{active: n == pagination.page}">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="pagination.toPageId(n)">{{n + 1}}</a>
 </li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first update your array which will contain only that much elements which will be shown on 5 pages.

You know the number of items showing on each page and also the number of pages. So You can updated your array of length (number of items showing on each page * 5)